# How to kill a process tree in Windows

Tags: perl, winapi, process, kill

Hi i have this process tree:

[image]

The above screenshot shows a process tree. In my Perl script i know the PID of dscli. I have written the following code to kill a single PID:

```
use Win32::Process;
use strict;
use warnings;

if(defined($ARGV[0])){
    my $pid = "$ARGV[0]";
    my $exitcode = 0;
    Win32::Process::KillProcess($pid, $exitcode);
}else{
    print "No argument provided :(\n";
}
```

The problem is that in my script i don't know the java process' PID. I have to get the dscli's child PID which is the java process. If i kill the dscli's PID using the above code then the child(java) don't die with it.

So my question is, how can i kill the java process which is the child of dscli using perl?

Comment: `getppid` is not implemented on Win32, which means just going through each process checking if a given PID is its parent won't work :(

Comment: There's a knowledgeable Perl/Windows user at http://www.perlmonks.org/

Comment: Also, if you can find out how to do it in C (using the API or WMI), I can help you port it to Perl.

Comment: `Win32::Process::Info` have `$pi->Subprocesses`

Answer (score 11):

You can use the Windows command `TASKKILL /T` to terminate a process and its child processes.

```
$pid = ...;
system("TASKKILL /F /T /PID $pid");
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use [WMI from PERL](http://talhatariq.wordpress.com/2006/06/20/a-perl-script-to-list-process-info-through-wmi-local-remote/). WMI is able to [find the PID of all child processes of a given parent](http://www.codequake.com/post/2010/09/11/How-to-get-a-list-of-child-processes-using-WMI-and-C.aspx). Note the query `"select * from win32_process where ParentProcessId={0}"`. If you have the list of child PIDs, you can call `Win32::Process::KillProcess`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest using WMI, but you might want to just call a VBScript from your Perl.  Here is a script that I use to kill by command line, which can help you narrow down a specific java process based on other things that were in the command line when it was launched:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then
strProcess = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
On Error Resume Next
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process")

If colProcessList.Count > 0 Then
    For Each objItem in colProcessList
        If InStr(objItem.CommandLine, strProcess) Then
            If (InStr(objItem.CommandLine, "cscript")) Then
            Else
                WScript.StdOut.Write objItem.Name + " "
                objItem.Terminate()
            End If
        End If
    Next
Else
    WScript.StdOut.Write "No instances found running"
End If
Else
WScript.StdOut.Write "Bad Arguments"
End If
```

Run it like this:

CScript whatEverYouNameIt.vbs "somethingInCommandLineLikeAClassName"